# HTML, AJAX, PHP - Send a html input array through ajax to a php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have seen many similar questions however I have tried them and none of them worked.

I have a form in which the user can enter an unspecified amount of inputs. These inputs are selects and the user can add them when required. I am using ajax to add in more selects as required.

I am then trying to post this array to a php page using ajax, eventually to insert into a database

This is my html:

```
<strong>Allergens:</strong><br><div id="allergens">
<select name="allId[]" id="allId">
    <option value="">No allergens</option>
    <?php
        $sql = ("SELECT AllergenId, LookupValue From ALLERGENS");
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<option value=".$row["AllergenId"].">".$row["LookupValue"]."</option>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</select><button type="button" class="addRemove" onClick="addAllergen()">+</button><br></div><br>
```

Here is what I insert to add in more selects:

```
<div id="newSelect">
<select name="allId[]" id="allId">
<?php
$sql = ("SELECT AllergenId, LookupValue From ALLERGENS");
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<option value=".$row["AllergenId"].">".$row["LookupValue"]."</option>";
        }
    }
?>
</select><button type="button" class="addRemove" onClick="removeNew()">-</button><br></div>
```

This is my ajax:

```
function addIng() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to submit?")) {
        var toPost ={};
        $form = $("#ingForm");
        toPost.allId = [];
        var allId = document.querySelectorAll("#ingForm input[name='allId[]']");
        for (i = 0; i < allId.length; i++) {
            toPost.allId.push(allId[i].value);
        }       
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../PHP/addIngredient.php",
            data: toPost,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#addIngResult").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And then how can I set up my php so I can just call `$_POST["allId"]` and put it into an array?

Comment: If i understood you correctly you want to pass all options of select as array?

Comment: No, the user can click a button to add another select. I want to pass all the selected values of these selects in an array. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think it doesnt make sense, because if u use <select> <option>
user can select only one option and only selected option can be passed. If you want user to be able to select one or more inputs u need to use input type="checkbox" insted of select

Comment: The page starts off with one <select>, the user can then press a button and add another identical <select>. I want to be able to pass the selected options from each of the selects into a array through ajax and into php

Comment: Ok, i think (im not sure) you need to pass all values of selects individually and then put them in array. So each select should have different name (allId[]<?php echo $i; ?>) and so on..

Answer (score 0):

On addIngredient.php page you will get the post value in $_POST['toPost'] variable as this is what writing in ajax

Comment: When I call my other fields it works though. I have an input called name and I can call '$_POST["Name"]' successfully. But when I echo through all of the keys in $_POST, allId isn't there